# Routing in Angular 2 and Asp MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing

i using angular 2 in asp mvc 5 .

i need to show `<my-app> </my-app>` content in view .

app.component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';   // Load all features
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { OtherComponent } from './other/other.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>My Name is {{name}}</h1>
    <other-app></other-app>`,
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/other', name: 'other', component: OtherComponent }
])
export class AppComponent {

    name = "Kianoush";
}
```

it show error to me :

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Build:Module '"F:/MyProject/angfinal/angfinal/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'ROUTER_PROVIDERS'.   angfinal    F:\MyProject\angfinal\angfinal\app\app.component.ts 3

.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Build:Module '"F:/MyProject/angfinal/angfinal/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouteConfig'.    angfinal    F:\MyProject\angfinal\angfinal\app\app.component.ts 3

.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   TS2305  Module '"F:/MyProject/angfinal/angfinal/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'ROUTER_PROVIDERS'. TypeScript Virtual Projects F:\MyProject\angfinal\angfinal\app\app.component.ts 3   Active

.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   TS2305  Module '"F:/MyProject/angfinal/angfinal/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouteConfig'.  TypeScript Virtual Projects F:\MyProject\angfinal\angfinal\app\app.component.ts 3   Active

.

other.component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'other-app',
    templateUrl: './app/other/other.component.html'
})
export class OtherComponent {
    name = "kianoush";
}
```

and header :

```
<head>
<base href="/">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

and config :

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "NotFound",
            url: "{*catchall}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and how can i show `other.component.html` in View and how can i solve this problem ??

Comment: you should focus on this line according the errormessage “import 'rxjs/Rx'”;

Comment: @Pengyy i remove this line but still show me error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have used older angular 2 router providers and services. if you have to use older version you should use [router-deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/router-deprecated). otherwise use new syntax described in [angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)